# Git version controls for multiple users with one solution

Tags: git

We are a small development team of just two people. We use an IIS server to publish applications when developing our web apps. We have started using GIT (visualstudio.com) for projects, but for the web apps we would like to keep the solution in the IIS server, not use the local debugger using IIS Express on our machines.
It appears from tests we can use both commit and push to the repository whilst accessing the same solution (on the IIS Server). Is there any gotcha's when using GIT in this way? Or does anyone have any recommendations? Perhaps each user working in a separate branch.

Comment: Are the files on the IIS Server shared? Means if you edit one file, it will be edited on your other developers solution too. If that is true, using git won't make sense.

Comment: You should set up a deployment script that pulls from git and places the file in the right location in the right way in the IIS folders. You should try to avoid "pushing to IIS".

Comment: Thank you both. Lance I understand your point, but we are using visualstudioonline as we need a back up facitily rather than as a way of sharing code. Is there an alternative product that would work better in this instance?

Comment: Than you Lasse for the information.